# Writing a dereference operator for iterator

Tags: c++, data-structures, iterator, set

I am writing a Set class in order to get a handle on how they really work, as well as to try to write my own Iterator. As far as I understand an Iterator is just a high level pointer that abstracts, well, iteration through a structure.

That being said I am aware that the important parts of an iterator are the ++ -- and * operations. I have successfully created and tested by in/decrement operators, but I am having a hell of a time conceptualizing *what* I need to return when I deference the Iterator.

Do I return the object it's pointing to?

Here is the relevant code in my set.h file:

```
class Set{
private:
    struct Elem {
        ELEMENT_TYPE info;
        Elem *prev, *next;
    };
    Elem *_head, *_tail;
    int _size;

public:
    //...

    class Iterator{
        private:
            Elem * _cur;

    public:
        Iterator(){}
        Iterator( Elem* );

        Iterator operator++( int );
        Iterator operator++();
        Iterator operator--( int);
        Iterator operator--();

        bool operator==( const Iterator& rhs );
        bool operator!=( const Iterator& rhs );

        Elem operator*();

    };

     //...
};
```

Like I said, I am returning the "Elem" that the Iterator is pointing to, is that correct?

```
Set::Elem* Set::Iterator::operator*(){

return _cur;
}
```

Comment: Please read the [operator overloading faq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading/4421719#4421719).

Comment: Did you miss the part that shows `value_type& operator*(); ` returning by reference which is the same as the answers?

Comment: Sure did miss that part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Usually* you'd return the element pointed to, by reference.

```
Elem&       operator*()       { return *_cur; }
```

It does depend a bit on the iterator type, though. Certain iterators (input iterators, e.g.) wouldn't necessarily return references.

Comment: @Joshua: Since `elem` is an internal node type, more like the iterator should return a reference to a `ELEMENT_TYPE`

Answer (score 1):

You'd normally return a reference, something like:

```
ELEMENT_TYPE & operator*() { return _cur->info;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `*` operator should return either the value or a reference

```
Set::Elem &Set::Iterator::operator*() {
    return *_cur;
}

const Set::Elem &Set::Iterator::operator*() const {
    return *_cur;
}
```

Comment: Usually, a `const` iterator returns a reference to mutable data, and a `const_iterator` returns a reference to immutable data.  Iterators (including pointers) are weird like that.  `const char*` vs `char*const`.